# Unable to change display resolution Ubuntu 18.04 on Xenserver VM

Tags: display-resolution, remote-desktop, vnc, xen

I'm using Dell T410 server with Free version of Xenserver 7.4, i installed Ubuntu 18.04 VM all went well but i'm unable to adjust the resolution

from ubuntu settings, showing just 800X600, see attached image taken from VNC Viewer but look the same if i use XenCentre or Xen Orchestra console. i also installed Windows 10 vm and using Microsoft RDP App installed on my iMac to access and it working ok i can change any resolution from both the VM or the RDP App settings and have sound. but on the Ubuntu i think it picks up the Dell driver\HW with no option to change the resolution, as you see from the screen shot even the setting page doesn't fit the screen. in general i would like to do the same as windows VM, RDP with Microsoft if possible as preferred. I did manage to use VNC Viewer but resolution was the same. i did install the XS Guest tools on both the Windows and Ubuntu vms but didn't help with the resolution on ubuntu. i also researched online but only found outdated solution from 2016 XS V6.5 and Ubuntu 16.04 but no solution helped.

I use this setup as a home lab to learn about  servers, linux CLI and VMs, so i wish to have a similar environment as a desktop.

my questions are :

1. how do i fix the resolution, do i need to install a XS or Ubuntu driver?
2. what you normally using in production and home lab environment to access the VM, RDP Client?
3. what RDP you recommend to get for best compatibility and environment as a desktop?

Thank you for your help

Yariv

[Ubuntu settings showing on VNC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxTNc.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but I can imagine, that this could work.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031143/unable-to-change-display-resolution-ubuntu-18-04-on-xenserver-vm

Answer (score 0):

1.Shutdown your VM.

2.From the command line, find the UUID of your VM:

xe  vm-list  name-label='Name of your VM'

3.Taking the UUID value, run the following command:

xe  vm-param-remove  uuid=UUID  param-name=platform  param-key=vga

4.You can always switch back to the default driver with the following command:

xe  vm-param-set  uuid=UUID  platform:vga=std